# How do I specify optional inputs on a Gradle task without an @Optional annotation?

Tags: gradle

I want to use an optional input if it exists and just move on if it does not exist.

When I run `gradle -Dorg.gradle.warning.mode=all` I got a deprecation warning for just specifying the input:

> A problem was found with the configuration of task ':addWorkingCopyInfo'. Registering invalid inputs and outputs via TaskInputs and TaskOutputs methods has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0.
>    - File '/Users/robert/test/special-build-tag' specified for property '$1' does not exist.

This is the task in the build script:

```groovy
task addWorkingCopyInfo(type: Exec) {
    inputs.file file("tagFile")   // deprecated if the file does not exist
    outputs.file file("generated/taginfo")
    executable "perl" args "..."
}
```

I've seen that I could add an `@Optional` annotation if I had a custom task class, but that's not the case here.

My best solution was to add a check for the file and only make it an input if it exists. This seems to work.

```groovy
task addWorkingCopyInfo(type: Exec) {
    def tagFile = new File("tagFile");
    if (tagFile.exists()) {
        inputs.file tagFile
    }
    outputs.file file("generated/taginfo")
    executable "perl" args "..."
}
```

Is there a better / more Gradle-ish way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `inputs.files(...)` returns a [`TaskInputFilePropertyBuilder`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputFilePropertyBuilder.html) that provides the methods `optional()` and `optional(boolean)`.

Just try:

```
inputs.files('my-file').optional()
```

Comment: I tried this answer and it doesn't work. I think it is actually incorrect. Please see https://discuss.gradle.org/t/what-is-taskinputfilepropertybuilder-optional-meant-to-do/41055/2 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/69340447/