# Why are optional inputs on my Gradle custom task not working?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a `build.gradle` with the following contents:

```
task myTask {
   inputs.file("input.txt").optional()
   doLast { println "input.txt exists = " + file("input.txt").exists() }
}
```

If `input.txt` doesn't exist, it fails with:

```
File '/Users/skissane/testgradle/input.txt' specified for property '$1' does not exist.
```

What I am trying to do, is run a custom script–which is written in Groovy, and runs inside the Gradle build under `doLast`, not as an external process–which takes the `input.txt` file as input, and the script's behaviour and output will change based on what is in that input file. But it is an optional input file – the script will still generate output (albeit different output) even if the input file doesn't exist.

Things I have tried so far:

1. Remove `.optional()`, change it to `.optional(true)`: no difference in results
2. Instead of `.optional()`, wrap it in `if (file("input.txt").exists()) {`: this works, but seems ugly. Why doesn't `.optional()` work?

Have I misunderstood what `.optional()` is meant to do? Because [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49640852/2147204) suggests it is the right way to solve my problem, but it isn't working.

(I am using Gradle 6.8.3. I tried upgrading to the latest Gradle 7.2, the same problem occurs, although 7.2 has more detailed error messages.)

Answer (score 1):

`optional()` can't be used to mark the file itself as optional. `optional()` just means that the input property is optional, and the task is still valid if no files at all are specified; but if a file is specified, it must exist.

As such, `optional()` isn't really useful in this kind of custom task declared directly in `build.gradle`. It is really intended for defining new task types in plugins, when one defines a new task input property other than `inputs`, and wants to make it optional to declare files for that property. It is the property itself which is made optional, not the files in it. On a custom task, declaring `inputs` as optional is pointless because it is already optional to begin with.

Right now (as of version 7.2), Gradle doesn't have any way to mark a file as an optional input, other than through `if (file("input.txt").exists()) {`. Hopefully they might add that feature in some future Gradle version.

(Thanks to James Justinic who answered [my post about this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/what-is-taskinputfilepropertybuilder-optional-meant-to-do/41055/2) on Gradle forums.)